# Possible to get ids created from MySQL

Tags: mysql

Let's say that I do a MySQL insert statement, of say:

```
"INSERT into tablename (column1, column2, column3) VALUES ("blah", "blahblah", "blahblahblah");
```

Is there anyway to know what row was created? Like, let's say there's a column4 which I am using as a primary, autoincrementing key, and I want to know which is the recently submitted value. Is that possible without querying the database again?

Comment: `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using mysql_insert_id() found here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Comment: P.S. not without submitting a new query as you never know what the last ID generated was or if other INSERT statements have been called since you last communicated.

Comment: How are you supposed to make a record on another table using the same key that was just generated then? Foreign key constraint?

Comment: The ID is remembered for you on a per connection basis so if you call mysql_insert_id() it will return the last ID you generated. This still has to be done with another call though.

Comment: What I meant in my first comment was that you can't select the last entry and assume that it was the one you inserted. It wasn't very clear when I read it again.